# Jackson set default view

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

### I am using Jackson 2.3.2, and I want to set the ObjectMapper default View

---

#### First try: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews#Implementation

```
// short-cut:
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, ViewsPublic.class);

// or fully exploded:
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationView(Views.Public.class);
// (note: can also pre-construct config object with 'mapper.copySerializationConfig'; reuse)
objectMapper.writeValue(out, beanInstance); // will use active view set via Config

// or, starting with 1.5, more convenient (ObjectWriter is reusable too)
objectMapper.viewWriter(ViewsPublic.class).writeValue(out, beanInstance);
```

So I had:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationView(ResourceView.PublicView.class);
```

Not works [JavaDoc **1.8.2** says:](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.html#setSerializationView%28java.lang.Class%29) `setSerializationView` is **deprecated**, I have to use `withView()`

---

#### Second try:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(ResourceView.PublicView.class);
```

Still not working. [JavaDoc **2.2.0** says](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig.html#withView%28java.lang.Class%29)

> `public SerializationConfig withView(Class<?> view)`
>
> Description copied from class: MapperConfigBase
>
> Method for constructing and returning a **new instance** with different view to use.

But I can't set the new `SerializationConfig` to the existing `ObjectMapper`

---

### How can I set default View?

---

#### UPDATE

I use Jersey and JAX-RS on the server side

Comment: Try and create an `ObjectWriter` using `mapper.writerWithView(ResourceView.PublicView.class)` and use that `ObjectWriter`

Comment: How can I use that `ObjectWriter` in my `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Jackson 2.4 (FINALLY) adds the setConfig() method to ObjectMapper: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setConfig(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jersey I had to set the View at the `JacksonJsonProvider`

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages("com.example.foo");

JacksonJsonProvider jjp = new JacksonJsonProvider();
jjp.setDefaultWriteView(ResourceView.PublicView.class);
config.register(jjp);
```

Answer (score 8):

It should work by doing:

```
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(ResourceView.PublicView.class));
```

Comment: Great, easy answer, but people should be aware - this is new in Jackson 2.4. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setConfig(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig)

Answer (score 0):

I use Jackson 1.9.13 and this works for me:

```
mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(ResourceView.PublicView.class));
```