# Ignore different fields in CSV and JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, export-to-csv

I have s Spring REST API that usually just outputs JSON.

Now I want to also export CSVs for some endpoints.

Jackson has a library for that

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Which I can utilize using Spring's `HttpMessageConverter`.

However I need to exclude some fields in the CSV that are present in the JSON thus I cannot use `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Is there a way to use a different ignore property/annotation for CSV?

As an alternative i considered using a custom interface to extract the values to serialize the values before hand. `List<CSVableDTO>` -> `List<Map<String,?>>` -> CSV. But I would like to avoid that because it involves extra instance creation and extra coding vs just using a new annotation.

Java-Class-Example:

```
public class MyDTO {

    @CSVIgnore
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String property;
    @CSVIgnore
    public String ref;

}
```

JSON-Example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "Example",
        "property": "FooBar",
        "ref": "42:Not:FooBar:1337"
    }
]
```

Expected-CSV-Result:

```
"name";"property"
"Example";"FooBar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider usage of [`JsonView` mechanism](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). You will have something like that:

```
public class Foo {

     public interface JsonOnly{}
     public interface CsvView{}

     @JsonView(JsonOnly.class) 
     private Integer secretNotForCsv;

     // ...

}

@RestController
public class FooController {

       @RequestMapping(...)
       @JsonView(Foo.JsonOnly.class)
       public Foo getJson() {
           // ...
       }

       @RequestMapping(...)
       @JsonView(Foo.CsvView.class)
       public Foo getCsv() {
           // ...
       }
}
```

This is only a very rough sketch, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: This looks like a promising solution. Although I don't want to create a new method in all my controllers to enable them to serve CSVs. (maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875642/jackson-set-default-view) can belp me to avoid duplicate methods.) I will test it and then report back.

Comment: I have some issues with the Jackson CSV mapper but your solution works (at least when using JSON).