# Jackson JsonView: Why all attributes have been serialized when no JsonView has been provided?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a class:

```java
package pro.abned.bug;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyPojo {
    private String property;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.Public.class)
    private String propertyPublic;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.Admin.class)
    private String propertyAdmin;
}
```

and here is the content of JsonViews:

```java
package pro.abned.bug;

public class JsonViews {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Admin extends Public {
    }
}
```

My goal is to make success the test below:

```java
package pro.abned.bug;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class MyPojoTest {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.defaultViewInclusion(true);
        objectMapper = builder.build();
    }

    @Test
    void testSerializeToObjectWithDefault() throws JsonProcessingException {
        assertThat(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MyPojo())).isEqualTo("{\"property\":null}");
    }

    @Test
    void testSerializeToObjectForPublic() throws JsonProcessingException {
        assertThat(objectMapper.writerWithView(JsonViews.Public.class).writeValueAsString(new MyPojo())).isEqualTo("{\"property\":null,\"propertyPublic\":null}");
    }

    @Test
    void testSerializeToObjectForAdmin() throws JsonProcessingException {
        assertThat(objectMapper.writerWithView(JsonViews.Admin.class).writeValueAsString(new MyPojo())).isEqualTo("{\"property\":null,\"propertyPublic\":null,\"propertyAdmin\":null}");
    }
}
```

Currently, **testSerializeToObjectWithDefault** test fails.
[image: Test results]

So, how to make jackson to ignore all annotated property when no JsonView has been provided to ObjectMapper or do not include anything in order to force the controller to specify a JsonView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875642/jackson-set-default-view